# Can you help me with this serieshelpmate problem?

Tags: checkmate, problems

I found a different kind of problem, a [serieshelpmate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seriesmover). I'm trying to get better by thinking outside of the box and solving different types of puzzles. So I found this one but I'm kind of stuck.

```
[FEN "1q4Nr/4K2k/8/8/8/8/1R6/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Now, Black makes 5 legal moves without a reply from White. After that White gives a mate in 1. How? I am familiar with the rook and knight mate but I just can't see it.

(@NoamElkies found the source, **with solution**: [Robert Pye, Irish Chess Union, November 2018](https://www.yacpdb.org/download/WCCI2016-18/G/G016-Pye,%20Robert.pdf))

Comment: There is no copyright associated with a chess problem itself, but the Codex of Chess Problem Conventions requests that when a problem is quoted, the author, source and year of publication are given. In practice, problemists only expect to see the composer’s name, but that they are very insistent about. There may be intellectual copyright associated with a printed image of a problem, but that has nothing to do with the content

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution by noting that

> - the rook can cover either one column or row
> - the knight already covers f6 and h6, so it's logical to let the rook take care of the g-file
> - we need the other black pieces to block the king's escape (but not being able to interpose a check by the rook)

It turns out that this sequence works:

> 1... Kg7 2... Rh1 3... Qh2 4... Qh8 5... Rh7 6. Rg2#

You can test it in the [Replayer Sandbox](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/910/7297); it supports null moves.

Comment: Mr. Moderator, is it permissible to post chess problems without acknowledging the source?

Comment: We don't have an explicit policy for this like Puzzling. I agree it would be good to credit the source, let's hope the OP comes back and adds it. Or somebody else who has seen this puzzle before.

Comment: Is it not official policy of stack exchange (if widely flouted) that all quoted matter must be attributed?

Comment: Sure, but copyright infringement claims are to be directed to the company, not to moderators. I'll have a look if I can find the source, that will be a nice puzzle as well :)

Comment: Apparently due to Robert Pye of Ireland, see
https://www.yacpdb.org/download/WCCI2016-18/G/G016-Pye,%20Robert.pdf
(which has several other nice series helpmates).